# In Xcode 4 iPhone Simulator not showing up

Tags: ios, sdk

Till yesterday only I was able to test my applications both on iPhone simulator as well as iPad simulator. But now I can run the application only on iPad simulator. It is working fine on iPad simulator. But if I select iPhone simulator and try to run the application, the iPhone simulator does not even show up. I am not able to understand the reason behind. I have checked all the settings repeatedly again and again.

Can please some one guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152559/ios-simulator-does-not-run/18820000#18820000

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your project's Build Settings has iPhone/iPad selected for the Targeted Device Family setting under the Deployment section.

Comment: the prob is sorted now....i uninstalled xcode and installed it again and all the problem was gone....thanks anyways John :-)

Comment: Glad you got it worked out, sorry the answer wasn't more useful for you.

Comment: This just saved me pulling my hair out... turns out I can't target iOS 6 when my machine doesn't even have it installed!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened to me ... when I updated to the latest version of XCode (4.3.2) I didn't bother to uninstall the previous version. I mistakenly opened my iOS 5.1 targeted project in the older version of XCode that does not know about 5.1 and as a result the simulator was not available. So i would check for the following:

See which version of XCode you're currently running
Try checking your iOS Deployment Target ... (Targets -> Deployment). If iOS 5.1 is selected change it to iOS 5.0 (the simulator will show up immediately)

Reference:
[Xcode 4 - IOS - Simulator not available as build target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121143/xcode-4-ios-simulator-not-available-as-build-target)

Answer (score 0):

change iOS Deployment Target as simulator iOS in build setting like simulator OS is 7.0 and iOS Deployment Target is 7.1 so simulator is not display