# Xcode 4 - IOS - Simulator not available as build target

Tags: xcode4, ios-simulator

I have a weird issue... I'm unable to find the simulator as a device in order to test my application. Anyone have any idea how to fix it? In a new project, it is available though.

[image: weird]

Regards,
EZFrag

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what happened to me ... when I updated to the latest version of XCode (4.3.2) I didn't bother to uninstall the previous version. I mistakenly opened my iOS 5.1 targeted project in the older version of XCode that does not know about 5.1 and as a result the simulator was not available.  So i would check for the following:

- See which version of XCode you're currently running
- Try checking your **iOS Deployment Target** ... (Targets -> Deployment).  If iOS 5.1 is selected change it to iOS 5.0 (the simulator will show up immediately)

Answer (score 5):

In additional to G.Bickham's answer, please make sure the iOS Simulator is downloaded.

To verify the download status, go to Xcode's **Preferences > Downloads > Components > iOS Simulator**

[image]

Comment: This can solve an issue where an iOS 7 simulator is selectable but when you try to run it you get a "X is not available" error in Xcode 6.