# Why do the C4 github examples lack support for an iPad simulator?

Tags: c4

I have recently downloaded the testScrollView and WalkCycle examples from https://github.com/C4Code, but the dropdown window in the topmost toolbar lacks the option to select iPad simulator as the target device. Do I have to have something enabled in order for this menu to display correctly, or is this an issue of incompatibility between C4/XCode versions?

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded to iOS 6, so all the projects I build and put up online will be targeted for iOS 6.0 simulator.

Check the following link, the answer there will show you how to change your settings so that it builds for the iOS 5.1 simulator:

[Xcode 4 - IOS - Simulator not available as build target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121143/xcode-4-ios-simulator-not-available-as-build-target)